# Share via Twitter Native App

Tags: android, twitter

I have android app where i am trying to add share feature via twitter.i have successfully implemented where the user can share via Twitter app :

This is my code:

```
Intent tweetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            tweetIntent.setType("text/plain");
            tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "tweet");
            tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "sample tweet");

            PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> lract = pm.queryIntentActivities(tweetIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            boolean resolved = false;
            for (ResolveInfo ri : lract) {
                if (ri.activityInfo.name.contains("twitter")) {
                    tweetIntent.setClassName(ri.activityInfo.packageName,
                            ri.activityInfo.name);
                    resolved = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(resolved){
                activity.startActivity(tweetIntent);
            }else{
                // do something
            }
```

Scenarios on click of button:

1) opens the `twitter native app` and if the user has already logged in it pass the control to `post tweet page` where my text will be added and on click of post it will successfully post.

**ISSUE scenario**

If the user has not logged in, user will `sign in`, after that it will move to `Home tab` where all the tweets are displayed, instead it should have moved to `post tweet page` where my text will be added.

how can i fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

As I remember this should work with native twitter

```
String twitterPackage = "com.twitter.android";
String errorMessage = "You should install Twitter app first";
if(isPackageInstalled(twitterPackage, getActivity())){
    Intent tweetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    tweetIntent.setType("text/*");
    tweetIntent.setPackage(twitterPackage);
    tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "sample tweet");
    getActivity().startActivity(tweetIntent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();// handle error
}
```

Comment: Yes it will but the issue is  : If the user has not logged in, user will sign in, after that it will move to Home tab where all the tweets are displayed, instead it should have moved to post tweet page where my text will be added.

Comment: sorry, but you can't change default twitter app behavior